# Scala Play : Consume raw data from play mvc api Request?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am getting an HTTP request from a camera feed that sends in about 4MB of raw data to my PlayFramework application every 10 seconds or so. Is there any good way to capture the raw data from the request and persist it to disk?

```
def uploadVideoChunk = Action(parse.raw) { request =>
    println(s"Got the request ${request.body.size}")

    val chunkOption = for {
      content = request.body
    } yield {
      VideoChunk(content)
    }

    chunkOption foreach { chunk =>
      val bytes = chunk.content.toString().getBytes
      Files.write(Paths.get("/tmp/video/", "ID-1", chunk.filename), ***???*** )
      println(s"wrote $chunk")
    }

    Ok("some response")
}
```

Comment: Not sure about how the camera sends the HTTP request, but maybe what you want is to [handle file upload](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaFileUpload).

Comment: Just a curl
`curl -LsS -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" --data-binary @- http://<ip>:<port>/uploadvideo`